# How to efficiently merge and possibly convolute two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle, array-merge

Suppose, that I have 3 arrays:

```
$a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];       // victim #1
$b = [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];  // victim #2
$result = [];           // result
```

I need to merge `$a` and `$b` in such order, that each element of `$a` array should be followed by element of array `$b`. Elements of `$b` array, however, might follow each other.

***For example:***

```
1 4 2 5 6 3 7 8
```

I have tried this:

```
while($a || $b)
    {
        $bool = rand(1, 100) >= 50;

        if($a)
            {
                $result[] = array_shift($a);
            }

        if($b)
            {
                $result[] = array_shift($b);
            }

        if($bool && $b)
            {
                $result[] = array_shift($b);
            }
    }
```

Which gives desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 8
)
```

However, I think that it might be inefficient because of [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array-shift)s and [`if()`](http://php.net/if)s appears too much times there.

**Question:** *Is there more efficient way to do that?*

***P.S.:*** Thanks, but I do really know how to use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array-merge). It is not the *RTM* issue.

Comment: I think your output is not exactly what you mean. You said that each of `$a` element must be followed by `$b` element. It means that your result must be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: should `$a` element follow after every 2 elements of `$b`. If not, after what interval should each `$a` follow `$b`?

Comment: @aaron at least one `$b` if there are `$b` elements.

Comment: @CORRUPT please clarify your comment. I don't understand at all

Comment: @david I mean **for example** section: `1 4 2 5 6 3 7 8`.

Comment: @david updated. I hope this will clarify what am I asking. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: @CORRUPT I have updated my answer. Hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($a as $value) {
    $result[] = $value;
    do {
        $bool = rand(0,1) == 1;
        $result[] = array_shift($b);
    } while ($bool);
}
// insert the remaining of value $b in the $result
foreach ($b as $value)
    $result[] = $value;
```

Comment: It will not mix elements in that order.

Comment: this will get result 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 base of your question

Comment: See example. Quote: `each $a element should be followed by $b element`.

Comment: Good attempt, +1. But works almost same. Will look what can do, based on this. `$a` may be empty however.

Comment: Inspired by your answer. Thanks for `do{ }while()` there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3 );       // victim #1
$b = array( 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);  // victim #2


foreach($a as $first)
{
   $result[] = $first;
}

foreach($b as $second)
{
   $result[] = $second;
}
```

Alternatively

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 9 );       // victim #1
$b = array( 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);  // victim #2
$result = array_merge($a,$b);
```